# Equation solver in python syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, error-handling, solver

I'm making a fast and simple equation solver in python for a home assaignment where I need to calculate the value of sig_a which is between 0 and 700 for each eps_komp. I've done this with 2 for loops, the first to select the eps_komp value and the second to search for the closest value of sig_a between 0 and 700 in order for the equation to be as close to zero as possible. I defined the allowable error with "delta".
It's similar logic like in bisection method. This is the code:

```
eps_komp = [0.00012893048999999997,
 0.018839115269999998,
 0.01230539995,
 0.022996934109999999,
 -0.0037319012899999999,
 0.023293921169999999,
 0.0036927752099999997,
 0.020621037629999998,
 0.0063656587500000002,
 0.020324050569999998]

Rm=700
sigma = np.linspace(0, Rm-0.01, Rm/0.01)
delta = 0.001
sig_a = []

for j in range(len(eps_komp)):
    eps_j = eps_komp[j]
    for i in range(len(sig)):
        eps_j - sigma[i]/Emod - (sigma[i]/RO_K)**(1/RO_n) = diff
        if diff <= delta:
            sig_a.append(sigma[i])
```

The values of eps_komp are just the first 10, there are more of them but I just gave the first 10 for an example.

Now I keep getting this error:

**SyntaxError: can't assign to operator**

I know it has something to do with an incorrect index but I just can't see the problem....

If anyone can help, it would mean a lot to me. Thanks.

Luka

Comment: to assign `diff` to the calculation it needs to be on the _left_ side of the equal sign: `diff = eps_j - sigma[i]/Emod - (sigma[i]/RO_K)**(1/RO_n)`

Comment: note that I still get an error about `sig` not being defined so there may be other issues with your code. (after adding `import numpy as np` that is)

Comment: thank you, I just switch the diff to front and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

to assign diff to the calculation it needs to be on the left side of the equal sign:

```
diff = eps_j - sigma[i]/Emod - (sigma[i]/RO_K)**(1/RO_n)
```